# Why my outer while loop doesn't work after the inner one stops?

Tags: c, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to create a function that displays all different combination of two digits between 00
and 99, listed by ascending order.
Here's what i wrote so far.

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)

{

    write(1, &c, 1);

}



void    ft_print_comb2(void)

{

    int x;

    int y;

    x = 0;

    y = x + 1;

    while(x <= 98)

    {

        while(y <= 99)

        {

            ft_putchar((x / 10) + '0');

            ft_putchar((x % 10) + '0');

            write(1, " ", 1);

            ft_putchar((y / 10) + '0');

            ft_putchar((y % 10) + '0');

            write(1, ", ", 2);

            y++;

        }

        x++;

    }

}



int main()

{

    ft_print_comb2();

    return (0);

}
```

My code stops after giving the output of 00 99. Why it doesn't add 1 to x and start from the outer while loop again?

Here's the desired output

```
00 01, 00 02, 00 03, 00 04, 00 05, ..., 00 99, 01 02, ..., 97 99, 98 99$>
```

Comment: you need to reset `y`. `for` loops are much better for what you're doing

Comment: Unfortunately in this assignment I am not allowed to use a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the variable `y` to the value `x + 1` before the inner while loop in each iteration of the outer while loop.

For example

```
x = 0;

while(x <= 98)

{
    y = x + 1;

    while(y <= 99)
    //...
```